# XCode Linker Errors, Undefined References, Templates, Const

Tags: c++, xcode, templates, linker, constants

I've got a form of an array class that uses templates. Because it is using templates, the entire class is declared and defined in the header file.

```
template<typename Type>
class KSArray
{
    friend bool operator==(const KSArray &lhs, const KSArray &rhs);
    friend bool operator<(const KSArray &lhs, const KSArray &rhs);

public:
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef Type value_type;

    KSArray();
    KSArray(const KSArray &k);
    KSArray& operator=(const KSArray &rhs);
    ~KSArray();
    KSArray(int n);
    KSArray(int n, value_type t);

    value_type& operator[](int index);
    const value_type& operator[](int index) const;

    size_type size() const;
    value_type* begin();
    value_type* begin() const;
    value_type* end();
    value_type* end() const;

private:
    size_type _size;
    value_type* _arrayPtr;
};
```

I've defined all of the functions and most of them work except the == and < operators. They are defined as follows:

```
template<typename Type>
bool operator==(const KSArray<Type> &lhs, const KSArray<Type> &rhs)
{
    if(lhs._arrayPtr==rhs._arrayPtr)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if(lhs._size==rhs._size)
    {
        for(size_t i=0;i<lhs._size;++i)
        {
            if(lhs->_arrayPtr[i]!=rhs->_arrayPtr[i])
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

template<typename Type>
bool operator<(const KSArray<Type> &lhs, const KSArray<Type> &rhs)
{
    if(lhs==rhs)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=0;i<min(lhs._size,rhs._size);++i)
        {
            if(lhs->_arrayPtr[i]==rhs->arrayPtr[i])
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if(lhs->_arrayPtr[i]<rhs->arrayPtr[i])
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return (lhs._size<rhs._size);
    }
}
```

When I run this code with my test file in main, I get a few linker errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator==(KSArray<int> const&, KSArray<int> const&)", referenced from:
      test_class_KSArray_equality_comparisons(Tester&) in ksarray_test.o
      bool operator!=<int>(KSArray<int> const&, KSArray<int> const&) in ksarray_test.o
      bool operator<=<int>(KSArray<int> const&, KSArray<int> const&) in ksarray_test.o
      bool operator><int>(KSArray<int> const&, KSArray<int> const&) in ksarray_test.o
  "operator<(KSArray<int> const&, KSArray<int> const&)", referenced from:
      test_class_KSArray_order_comparisons(Tester&) in ksarray_test.o
      bool operator<=<int>(KSArray<int> const&, KSArray<int> const&) in ksarray_test.o
      bool operator><int>(KSArray<int> const&, KSArray<int> const&) in ksarray_test.o
      bool operator>=<int>(KSArray<int> const&, KSArray<int> const&) in ksarray_test.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

As the error suggests, I use the == and < operators in my other operators in order to minimize the code I have to write. **From the research I've done, I think the issue is with my placement of const and perhaps Type. I've tried moving them around and tweaking them to no avail. Any ideas?**

I'm using XCode 4.6 with the Apple LLVM 4.2 C++ compiler on Mac OS X 10.8.2.

Comment: So right out of the gate, please specify the **filename** that each of the aforementioned code slices are contained in. If what I'm thinking is the problem, you should follow that up with reading [this question and answer set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file/495056#495056) to understand why templates (***including free-function operators like your comparison operators***) must be implemented in a *header file*. I don't think it coincidence these two code chunks (class and ops) are in different snippet blocks in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to my professor, I found out that templates and friends work slightly oddly: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/template-friends.html

Using the above link, I was able to figure out how to fix my issue. During my initial research, I wasn't aware that the issue dealt with friends and templates. I thought it was an issue with const or something weird.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try **explicit** keyword before your constructor. It looks like to me that you are facing problem of conversion constructor and your int argument is implicitly getting converted into KSArray..